# javascript element.scrollLeft not working

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm experimenting with sliders.

I want to be able to scroll to a particular position of my slider and it seems from MDN docs that I could use element.scrollLeft to scroll to a particular position.

I does not seem to be working for me though..

`var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.scrollLeft = 150;`

http://codepen.io/veraz/pen/yVGWPP

window.scrollTo(150, 0) works though, but why?
What's the difference between using one or the other?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to make the element scrollable while working with scrollLeft

Check the docs here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

it says.

scrollLeft can be set to any integer value, however:

If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow), scrollLeft is set to 0.

If set to a value less than 0 (greater than 0 for right-to-left elements), scrollLeft is set to 0.

If set to a value greater than the maximum that the content can be scrolled, scrollLeft is set to the maximum.

So if you do the below change in your css this will work.

```
#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLZNrW

Comment: thanks so much!
would you know if its better/more efficient to use element.scrollLeft or window.scrollTo...?

Comment: for me it depends upon what other elements are there. if there is a single element like this example then both works fine. If there are few other elements present which need not to be scrolled then window.scrollTo() is if no use since it will scroll entire window.