# Horizontal scrolling of div not working with scrollLeft

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make horizontal scrolling with scrollLeft. I'm able to align div horizontally but it looks like the scrollLeft function is not working.

Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: auto;
  display:inline-flex;
  gap:10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll div</button><br><br>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I applied the `white-space` and `overflow` style inside the `#myDiv` style; I set the `width` property to `220px` to follow the `scrollLeft`<sup>[1]</sup>.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.scrollLeft += 50;
}
```

```css
#myDIV {  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 220px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll div</button><br><br>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
    <div id="content">
  Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
  Some text inside a div element.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1 - [JavaScript element.scrollLeft not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41205187/15032688)</sup>